# Different ways of using import statements

Tags: python

I'm using `models.py`, `forms.py`, `views.py` etc. in my Django Project.

Whenever I need a class from e.g. `models.py` in e.g. `views.py`, I add an import statement at the top:

```
from .models import MyModel, MyModel2, MyModel3
```

... and then use the model as `MyModel` in my view.

This list is getting quite long though (especially the case with `forms`).

Is there any downside of using the following:

```
from . import models
```

... and then using `models.MyModel` in my view?

Possible downsides I could think of are security and execution speed. Are my concerns valid?

Comment: No. What security implications could you mean? And the speed is *exactly* the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, these are exactly the same, and I'm not sure why you think they could be different. As [PEP 8 says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), though, the second way (`import models`, then using `models.MyModel`) is recommended, because it avoids cluttering the local namespace. If you still want to do it the first way for whatever reason, you can use `from .models import *`, although that is discouraged by PEP 8 for the same reason.